# Angular Firebase simplelogin

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

When I use construction like

```
 ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
        console.log("User ID: " + authData.uid + ", Provider: " + authData.provider);
    }, {
        remember: "sessionOnly",
        scope: "email"
    });
```

All is working:

```
User ID: facebook:..., Provider: facebook 
User ID: google:..., Provider: google
.... and others.
```

When I use construction

```
 var authClient = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
 authClient.$login("google", {
        remember: "sessionOnly"
    });
```

I see an error '400. That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to properly set `REDIRECT URIS` in your *Google Developers Console* page.

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/, authenticate (:-), select `APIs & Auth`, `Credentials`, and fill `REDIRECT URIS` field with the url `https://auth.firebase.com/auth/google/callback`.

Comment: I've used https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MYFIREBASE/auth/google/callback url. With https://auth.firebase.com/auth/google/callback login worked. But there is a warning FIREBASE WARNING: FirebaseRef.auth() being deprecated. Please use FirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken() instead.  I didn't use this method = it means that  authClient.$login("google"...) deprecated?

Comment: Are you using firebase 1.1?

Comment: //Firebase
script(src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js')
script(src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.3/firebase-simple-login.js')

Comment: Since Firebase 1.1 they undergo a code rewriting, including firebase-simple-login into firebase core, and changing a bit the APIs; and yes, login() is now deprecated, for auth(), authWith...(), onAuth()... I did try to upgrade my project to Firebase 1.1.1, but for the moment I stay with 1.0.x for some incompatibilities with my code base... More, if you use AngularFire, be sure it supports Firebase 1.1...